# C: memcpy changes pointer?

Tags: c

Does `memcpy` adjust the pointer to the copied data if the data referenced by the pointer is also within the scope of `memcpy`? (I assume not, but one never knows...)

So assume, for instance, copying a pointer the content that this pointer references to. The question is: Is the pointer copied dumbly (i.e. without changes) or is it adjusted to point to the newly copied content?

Comment: have you tried it and checked the result?

Comment: @Default you never know because it might be UB. ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)

Comment: Can anyone clarify the question?What does the OP mean?

Comment: @SheerFish i'm assuming he is taking about overlapping source and destination buffers. which is UB

Comment: @Koushik I am also confused about the downvote I got.I had long assumed that's what memcpy() is all about.Can you point where I went wrong in my answer before I delete it?Frankly,I see none.

Comment: Wow, I didn't expect that many answers in such a short time! I tried and it of course and it just dumbly copied one by one; but I couldn't really be sure. Sorry if it is a too stupid question! @SheerFish, I did not downvote your answer, so sorry for that! I will edit the question above for clarification.

Comment: @navititious Nothing about the downvote mate.People have solid reason in this forum if they downvote something.So I was curious.But PLEASE clarify you question as I want to understand what you want to ask.Many people have understood it but it's too tough for me to grasp what you intend to ask.It must be something substantial, else people wont' have bothered giving their fine answers.I see memcpy() as something that simply copies stuff from one location to another.So I am at a loss about "adjusting the pointer" and stuff.I feel I am missing out in the discussion.Plz clarify your question.

Comment: So from what I understood memcpy just dumbly copies content from memory and does no adjustments of e.g. pointers and stuff. So that's basically already everything I needed to know :-) thanks!

Comment: @navititious I don't understand where the question of adjustment of pointers arise, as memcpy() simply copies stuff from one address (specified by one pointer) to another address specified by another pointer.Isnt that so?

Comment: Yes, sure! No I know for sure! Sorry if the question is too stupid, but when looking for bugs, any possibility arises ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

no, memcpy blindly copies x bytes from source to destination.

See for instance: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcpy.3.html

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcpy.3.html

Comment: @jsalonen: did you just edit this question to insert a `.` or am I missing something?

Comment: No I edited to insert the URL seen above, but deleted it since it's better to be placed in the comments as done right now. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @jsalonen oh! you didn't change the edit description. it says you added 55 characters, but I could only see 1. I though you had 54 characters hidden or something. :) thanks for explaining. (personal off topic note though: I would think that the link might as well be incorporated in the answer since it's a good reference.)

Comment: Ok added the link back with description "see for instance" so that I don't push the answer too much into what I think it is about :)

Answer (score 1):

`memcpy` does not modify any pointers; it only modifies the contents of the memory block pointed by the `dst` parameter.

`memcpy` **should not be used if two memory blocks overlap in any way**. In such case `memmove` should be used.

Answer (score 0):

What `memcpy` does internally is outside the scope of the specification. Externally, any changes to any pointers are not visible, because `memcpy` works with copies of the pointers that are passed as arguments.

Comment: Hey Oswald, is my understanding of memcpy() as I have mentioned in my answer faulty?Can you clarify what the OP wants to ask?I am very confused about the question.

Answer (score 0):

In accordance to [this](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/invisible/src/crt/memcpy.c.htm) source, it does not.

Answer (score 0):

According to the standard, the behavior is undefined, if source and target-pointer overlap.

Example from [`valgrind`](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/valgrind/valgrind_49.html)-manual

```
==27492== Source and destination overlap in
            memcpy(0xbffff294, 0xbffff280, 21)
==27492==    at 0x40026CDC: memcpy
               (mc_replace_strmem.c:71)
==27492==    by 0x804865A: main (overlap.c:40)
```

You don't want the two blocks to overlap because one of them could get partially overwritten by the copying.

...

In addition, for many of these functions, the POSIX standards have wording along the lines “If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined.” Hence overlapping copies violate the standard.

Look [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memcpy), too:

```
Description
The memcpy() function copies n bytes from memory area src to memory area dest.
The memory areas must not overlap. Use memmove(3) if the memory areas do overlap.
```

Comment: @Downvoter what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The prototype for `memcpy()` is

```
 void * memcpy ( void * destination, const void * source, size_t num );
```

It copies the values of num bytes from the location pointed by source directly to the memory block pointed by destination.It returns  a pointer to the destination.

Comment: Is my understanding of this function wrong?I had assumed it copies the desired number of bytes to the destination and returns a pointer to that destination.Am I wrong?

Comment: nothing wrong here but try adding suggestion that its UB and why it is so.dont know why the downvote though.

Comment: @Koushik UB means unbuffered eh?Or what?

Comment: its undefined behaviour.